# What creatures are there that adopt and take care of children?

Tags: mythical-creatures

I really want to know if there is a creature that adopts or take care of children. I tried to find one myself but it almost shows a creature that scares children or eats them which is the opposite of what I want.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

In mythology, there are plenty of examples, the best known are:

- Romulus and Remus were nursed by the [Capitoline Wolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitoline_Wolf)
- [Enkidu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enkidu), raised by unspecified beasts, becomes the friend of the hero Gilgamesh
- [Atalanta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atalanta) was raised by a she bear after her father abandoned her in a forest

In real life, we have documented cases:

- [Dina Sanichar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dina_Sanichar), discovered among wolves in a cave in Sikandra (near Agra) in Uttar Pradesh, India in 1872, at the age of 6.
- [Marcos Rodríguez Pantoja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcos_Rodr%C3%ADguez_Pantoja) (ca. 1946, Sierra Morena, Spain) lived for 12 years with wolves in the mountains of Southern Spain. He was discovered at age 19

See here for a [list of documented cases of feral children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feral_child#Documented_cases_of_feral_children). Note that the veracity for many in this list is contended.